Repeating sum of no. of terms in a sequence
In the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$, the sum of any three consecutive terms is 40; if the third term is $10$ and the eighth term is $8$; find the $2013$th term.
I see that if there is a sequence of no. such that $x, y, z, x, y, z, x, y, z, \ldots$ then the sum repeats. Thus, I find that the series is $22, 8, 10, \ldots$. Now $2013$ is divisible by $3$ and so the required answer should be $10$ but it is given as $8$.

You don't even need information about the $8^{th}$ term.  As $3,|,2013$, we know that $a_{2013}=a_3=10$.  Something seems off in the problem statement.

Looks like a typing/printing mistake in the book.
